# set session variables PHP from PhoneGap

Tags: php, ajax

I've created a login page in Phonegap. The login with database runs ok, but when i try to create a session variables in PHP  not set. This only happens in local (phonegap) if i try in server runs ok.

This is my ajax script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(res);
    if(callback && res.status != 9){ // status = 9 means session start but not set
        callback(res);
        } // END IFs
    else {
        localStorage.clear();
        app.checkUser();
        } // END ELSE
    } // END IF
} // END FUNCTION
```

This is my PHP:

```
session_start();

$user = $_POST['user'];
$name= $_POST['name'];

$data->session_status = session_status(); // this is to check if session start
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$data->id_session = $session_id();
$data->session = $_SESSION; // check if session sets ok

echo json_encode($data);
```

But if i call another php script. This not restart the previous session

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$id_session = $_POST['id_session'];
session_start();
if($user == $_SESSION['user'] && $id_session == session_id()) {
// do somthing... 
}
else {
data->status = 9;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And this my htaccess header set:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * // to accept phonegap request
```

Answer (score 0):

use
session_start();
in another php script also

Comment: Hi. I tried it, but it creates another session. I've search info and it seems can't create php session or set cookies when request is from inappbrowser system (Phonegap or similar), even if set Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *. So i don't know how can create a session and persist data